# Haskell 64 bit numerical type

Tags: haskell, types, integer, numerical

I am writing a function in Haskell that deals with numbers beyond the length of a 32 bit int. I cannot find the type to do this and I seem to be searching for the wrong terms.

It needs to be able to hold numbers with the length of about 2^40 without any loss of precision

Example:

```
addTwo :: Int -> Int -> Int
addTwo a b = a + b

main :: IO()
main = do
    putStrLn ( show ( addTwo 700851475143 1 ) )
```

Comment: ironically, if you hadn't put the signature for addTwo in, it would have worked, because addTwo would have been inferred to be polymorphic (i.e. Num a => a -> a -> a), and then for the numbers, it would have defaulted to the most general type, which is Integer

Comment: But I wouldn't have learnt anything, which is the whole point

Answer (score 21, accepted):

For unbounded precision, use the Integer type. For 64 bits of precision, across platforms, use Data.Int.Int64. Both will be easy to find with Hoogle: http://haskell.org/hoogle/

Answer (score 7):

You want the `Integer` data type instead of `Int`:

```
addTwo :: Integer -> Integer -> Integer
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `Integer`, which is unlimited precision,  instead of `Int`.